# Sorting a list based on the valeus of outer and inner tuple(Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of the form

```
l = [(98, (99, 1)),(97, (97, 3)),(97, (100, 3))]
```

I want to sort this list based on the first value of outer tuple and the first value of inner tuple: 
(**98**, (**99**, 1)). I want to get the following result:

```
[(98, (99, 1)),(97, (100, 3)),(97, (97, 3))]
```

what is the best way to do it in python?

Comment: Is "the first value of the outer tuple" the primary sort key?  If so, why does your desired output have `98` before `97`?

Comment: Or are you saying the sort key is the **sum** of those two items?

Comment: @JohnGordon I believe the OP missed the word "descending" somewhere…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom sorting function:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]), reverse=True)
```

Yields:

```
[(98, (99, 1)), (97, (100, 3)), (97, (97, 3))]
```

Answer (score 3):

As it happens,

```
l.sort(reverse=True)
```

will sort the list exactly as you want.